# Method returns HttpStatusCode in angular

Tags: angular, httprequest, http-status-codes, angular15

I want to make a method that only makes another request when the before request return StatusCode 200. I'm using angular 15.

My `home.component.ts` look like this and I want to `todasGuias()` only make another request at a time.

```
    todasGuias() {
    this.page= 1;
    while (this.page <= this.listaGuias.TotalPages) {
      this.homeService.getGuias( this.year, this.month, this.glosadas, this.page)
      .subscribe((data)=>{
        this.listaGuias = data.Dados[0]
        console.log(this.listaGuias.ResultList);
      })
      this.page++;
    }
  }
```

and my `home.service.ts` look like this:

```
 public getGuias( year: any, month: any, glosadas: any, page:any): Observable<any> {
    const token = this.token.retornaToken();
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` });

    return this.http.get(API/list?TpoRelatorio=1
    &SomenteGlosadas=${glosadas}
    &Ano=${year}
    &Mes=${month}
    &Page=${page}
    &Count=0`,{ headers }
    )
  }
```

any help?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the rxjs operator [`switchMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap) to achieve this:

```js
todasGuias() {
    range(1, this.listaGuias.TotalPages).pipe(
       switchMap(page => this.homeService.getGuias( this.year, this.month, this.glosadas, page))
    ).subscribe((data)=>{
        this.listaGuias = data.Dados[0]
        console.log(this.listaGuias.ResultList);
      })
    }
  }
```

This assumes you know the total number of pages beforehand. `range` generates an Observable with every number from 1 to TotalPages. `switchMap` then maps each number to an Observable executing the http request. As `switchMap` only retains one subscription internally all the requests are made sequentially. If one request fails, the Observable will also fail.

Comment: it didn't work, it makes the request just of the first page

Comment: Are you sure that `this.listaGuias.TotalPages` is set correctly while calling the function? This approach only works, if the `this.listaGuias.TotalPages` are known at the time the function is called.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. example: if TotalPages is 3 it makes 3 requests of the first page

Comment: So I tested it again. It works for me. The only thing I can think of is that you wrote `this.page` instead of just `page` in the function parameters of `this.homeService.getGuias`.